# Pagination using associtive array

Tags: php, pagination

I have the following script, which will paginated results from an array... but only when using a numeric key value. Can this script be modified to work with an associative array using a string value for the key? I need to do that to sort the array alphabetically, with the eventual aim of pagination in an alphabetical fashion.

Here the script so far.

```
$my_array = array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c'); // THIS WORKS FINE

//$my_array = array('a' => 'a', 'b' =>'b', 'c'=>'c'); // THIS DOESN'T WORK

$arr = $my_array; 

$rows_per_page = 1;

$numrows = count($arr);

// Calculate number of $lastpage
$lastpage = ceil($numrows/$rows_per_page);

// condition inputs/set default
if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
   $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
} else {
   $pageno = 1;
}

// validate/limit requested $pageno
$pageno = (int)$pageno;
if ($pageno > $lastpage) {
   $pageno = $lastpage;
}
if ($pageno < 1) {
   $pageno = 1;
}

// Find start and end array index that corresponds to the requested pageno
$start = ($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page;
$end = $start + $rows_per_page -1;

// limit $end to highest array index
if($end > $numrows - 1){
    $end = $numrows - 1;
}

// display array from $start to $end
for($i = $start;$i <= $end;$i++){
    echo $arr[$i] . '<br />';
}
echo "<p style='text-align:center;'>";

// first/prev pagination hyperlinks
if ($pageno == 1) {
   echo " FIRST PREV ";
} else {
   echo " <a href='?pageno=1'>FIRST</a> ";
   $prevpage = $pageno-1;
   echo " <a href='?pageno=$prevpage'>PREV</a> ";
}

// Display current page or pages
echo " ( Page $pageno of $lastpage ) ";

// next/last pagination hyperlinks
if ($pageno == $lastpage) {
   echo " NEXT LAST ";
} else {
   $nextpage = $pageno+1;
   echo " <a href='?pageno=$nextpage'>NEXT</a> ";
   echo " <a href='?pageno=$lastpage'>LAST</a> ";
}

echo "</p>";
?>
```

Comment: "Can this script be modified to work with an associative array using a string value for the key?" yes it can

Comment: Try using `$my_array = array('a' => 'a', 'b' =>'b', 'c'=>'c'); `. And turn on the error notification of notices and warnings. You would've gotten an error.

Comment: Hint: the problem lies in this line for($i = $start;$i <= $end;$i++)

Comment: @Lex - Sorry, I just scribbled out the arrays for example purposes... my actual array is fine ;) I'll amend this in my question. Pankrates - yes I though as much.. but my noob skill level can't work out what... maybe you can kindly be more specific? Please?

Comment: why the down vote? I asked a question, what's to vote down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to an associative array by a numerical index, replace

```
for($i = $start;$i <= $end;$i++){
    echo $arr[$i] . '<br />';
}
```

with:

```
$arr_keys = array_keys($arr);
for($i = $start;$i <= $end;$i++){
    echo '-'.$arr[$arr_keys[$i]] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: thanks so much.. so as it turns out, I did know what the problem was, but couldn't get the syntax right having tried something similar before asking my question. Thank you again for putting me right ;)